# Reading a text file in PowerShell after of a marker

Tags: powershell, text, text-files

I'm just wondering if it's possible to read the content of text file with specific index?

What I mean is like this, for example:

I have text file like this, 'test1.txt'

> 12345678900 ## ## readthistext
>
> 54321123440 ## ## hellothistext

I just want to read the content of text file after of the hashtag.

Comment: look at indexOf or regex examples in powershell.  If you have some code you have written we could look at that and help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the text after the `#` characters you must read the file content up to the `#` characters first. Also, in PowerShell you normally read files either line by line (via [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content)) or completely (via `Get-Content -Raw`). You can discard those parts of the read content that don't interest you, though. For instance:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\input.txt') -replace '^.*#'
```

The above will read the file `C:\input.txt` and for each line remove the text from the beginning of the line up to the last `#` character.

Comment: This is not working, still its reading the whole line of the text file.

Comment: The code worked fine when I tested it. Please provide evidence.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry. Yes it's working, but my actual string is this one '|' pipeline. I tried to put -replace '^.*#|' like that and it didnt work. Because I think powershell cant exclude the pipeline string.

Comment: The pipe character (`|`) has a special meaning in regular expressions, so it must be escaped: `-replace '^.*\|'`

Comment: Sweet, this works fine! Last one thing, what if I have data on my text file like this. 12345 #### C:\test\file\test.txt and then I want just to get the string 'C:\test\file'

Comment: Pipe the output to a loop where you extract the directory name from the path: `... | % { [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_) }`

Comment: Awesome! You're really awesome, thank you bunch! Saved my lifeee.

Comment: On second thought, using `Split-Path` instead of a loop might be an even better approach: `... | Split-Path -Parent`

Comment: Yes I also thought of this one! But still thank you!